# LoginTestListView is missing a QuerySet. Define LoginTestListView.model, LoginTestListView.queryset, or override LoginTestListView.get_queryset()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Why such a mistake?

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/
Django Version: 2.2.18
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:
LoginTestListView is missing a QuerySet. Define LoginTestListView.model, LoginTestListView.queryset, or override LoginTestListView.get_queryset().
Exception Location: C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py in get_queryset, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:
['C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\geekshop',
'C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\geekshop',
'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm '
'2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm_display',
'C:\Users\isp06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\isp06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Users\isp06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
'C:\Users\isp06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
'C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\venv',
'C:\Users\isp06\Documents\test\geekshop-server\venv\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm '
'2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Fri, 26 Mar 2021 17:18:20 +0000

```
enter code here
class LoginTestListView(ListView):

       template_name = 'authapp/login.html'
       form_class = UserLoginForm


       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super(LoginTestListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          context['title'] = 'GeekShop - Авторизация'
          return context


enter code here

 urlpatterns = [
path('login/', LoginTestListView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('register/', register, name='register'),
path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
path('new-logout/', new_logout, name='new_logout'),






enter code here

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Введите имя пользователя'
    self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Введите пароль'
    for fild_name, field in self.fields.items():
        field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control py-4'
```

Comment: It looks like what you here have is not a `ListView`, but something like a `FormView`.

Answer (score 0):

A [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) requires that you specify a model, or a `queryset`, or override `get_queryset` since, well…, it is a view that is supposed to render a list (collection) of things.

But your view does not seem to do that. This looks more like a [**`FormView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView). In the [**`.form_valid(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) method you can then implement logic what to do when the form is valid:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'authapp/login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginTestListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'GeekShop - Авторизация'
        return context
```

Comment: error  class LoginTestListView(ListView):   LoginView

Comment: @Nikolos: but you shoul *inherit* from the `FormView`...